# Assign/Compare DateTime value from Database with DateTime value from C# in Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

I have following class:

```
public class Top10Date
    {
        [Key]
        public int DateId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    }
```

Which is associated with Top10Date table in database. 
I am trying to do a comparison and assign values to latestDate in controller class:

```
public ActionResult Index(string date, DateTime? latestDate)
    {
        var topDate = db.Top10Dates;

        if (!latestDate.HasValue)
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());


       if (date.Value == "PreviousDate")
        {
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate.Date).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());                
        }

        if (date.Value == "NextDate")
        {
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        .... 

        ViewBag.latestDate = latestDate

        return View();
    }
```

But it is giving me all sort of errors. I have tried other things too but none are working:

```
latestDate = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
latestDate.Value = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();

latestDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Value.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also how can i get DateId from the Database? I tried this it is now working.

```
var dateId = (DateTime?)top10Date.Where(d => d.Date == latestDate.Value.Date).Select(x => x.DateId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (!latestDate.HasValue)
    latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Select( x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());    

if (date == "PreviousDate")
{
    latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate.Date).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
}

if (date == "NextDate")
{
    latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Your query on `topDate` is returning an instance of `Top10Date` which cannot be automatically converted to `DateTime?`.  You can use the linq method `Select()` to have your query return something different - in this case the `Date` property in `Top10Date`

Comment: Thanks for the query i am trying this! But am stuck at one more point. There is another place where latestDate is used: var topTitles = topsong.Where(s => s.DateId == latestDate).ToList();    This is also comparing Database date from another table where DateId is foreign key to. Any ideas how i can use latestDate here?

Comment: I tried to get DateId using this: var dateId = (DateTime?)top10Date.Where(d => d.Date == latestDate.Value.Date).Select(x => x.DateId).FirstOrDefault(); But this is now working?

Comment: +1 from me for the help. I would give more but am not able to do that :) . Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You are welcome.  You should probably read up on `linq` - this is the part of the .Net framework where all magic around `Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy` etc lives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code if someone else had similar problem. It took me whole day to figure this out. And i cant thank StanK enough for showing me the right path:

```
if (!latestDate.HasValue)
            {
                latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
            }


           if ( date == "PreviousDate")
            {
                latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());                
            }

            if (date == "NextDate")
            {
                latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate).OrderBy(d => d.Date).Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
            }
```

Also here is how to get the DateId of the latestDate:

```
    int dateId = topDate.Where(d => d.Date == latestDate).Select(x => x.DateId).FirstOrDefault();
```